# Request denied while updating user details in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails.

I've two type of users Admin and User. Admin can create edit and destroy user. I've no problem with create and destroy and have implemented quite easily.

I've used following code in controller,

```
private

def allowed_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :fname, :lname)
end
```

to define parameters required and allowed while creating user.

**User Create**

```
def save_user
    @user = User.new(allowed_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to list_users_path
    else
        render 'add_user'
    end
end
```

**User Update**

```
def update_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(allowed_params)
        redirect_to list_users_path
    else
        render 'edit_user'
    end
end
```

**View**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= link_to "Admin Dashboard", admin_dashboard_path, :class=>'pull-left' %>
      <%= form_for @user, :url => update_user_path do |f| %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 field">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <h2 style="text-align: center;">Edit User Details</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 field">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <%= f.label :fname, 'First Name' %><br />
              <%= f.text_field :fname, :class => 'form-control' %>
              <p class="error"><%= show_errors(@user, :fname) %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 field">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <%= f.label :lname, 'Last Name' %><br />
              <%= f.text_field :lname, :class => 'form-control' %>
              <p class="error"><%= show_errors(@user, :lname) %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 field">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <%= f.label :email, 'Email' %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
                <p class="error"><%= show_errors(@user, :email) %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 field">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center">
              <%= f.submit "Update User", :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I pass only fname, lname and email nothing happened. I need to update user details what should I do here ?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: "Nothing happened" - which page was rendered? Try to update with bang `@user.update_attributes!(allowed_params)` and see if you have an exception and what is the exception.

Comment: A word of advice advise is to stick to the rails conventions and call your methods `save` and `update` and not `update_user` as this lets you use convention over configuration instead of manually specifying the routes.

Comment: When I click the submit button in update case nothing happend, I'll share my view one minute.

Comment: You probably have validation errors. Please try with `update_attributes!` and check if any error is raised.

Comment: @mrzasa no error is displayed on form element, what could be the reason ? any idea

Comment: 1) Can you find the console output to terminal, or log files? 2) If you open the developer console in your browser, what status code do you see when you submit your form? Are the submitted parameters what you expect?

Comment: @rwold I'll see, I've just started learning rails since 2 days and i don't have good knoledge

Answer (score 0):

There is a debug way.

1. You should launch the server in development mode. Then check the changes of development.log file in the terminal by `tail -f log/development.log`.
2. Then do what you want, such as click the "submit" button when you changed the fname or other fields.
3. Then focus on the informations got on step 1. There are what you can get:

   `A. which Controller and action handled the request`

   `B. The parameters of this request.`

   `C. The log of SQLs excuted by DB`

   `D. The response status`

   Check if the right Controller? or right parameters? or SQLs has been excuted? In addition， we used to `@user.update_attributes!(allowed_params)` when debug. It take more informations when something disobeys the rules defined in Model(User).